# GET_LOCK succeeds when shouldn't have within two (ought to be) separate connections via PHP MySQL/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, session, locking

The scenario is quite simple. We have a PHP script which:

- executes MySQL query `GET_LOCK('TEST', 0)`
- sleeps 5 seconds
- executes MySQL query `RELEASE_LOCK('TEST')`

Open a web browser and call the above script in 2 separate tabs but with a delay of 1-2 seconds between the calls.

- **Expected result**: 1st call acquires the 'TEST' lock, 2nd call fails to acquire 'TEST' lock.
- **Actual result**: 1st and 2nd call both acquire TEST' lock.

Persistent connections are disabled in PHP.INI and no specific connection options are used to enable them. Both MySQL and MySQLi extensions produce the same result. Tested on two setups: PHP 5.3.9 + MySQL 5.5.20; PHP 5.4.4 + MySQL 5.5.35.

The strange thing is that executing the same scenario via the terminal, workbench or even different browsers actually works as expected. I can reproduce the problem only by calling the script within the same browser (no mater which one in particular, Opera, Firefox, Chrome, etc).

I have found [Bug #62002](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62002) on MySQL website which describes exactly same issue, but it was never solved or explained. It was suggested in the bug report to execute `SELECT @@pseudo_thread_id` and in my case it produces sometimes the same number, sometimes different.

I suspect that both calls for some bizarre reason get executed on the same physical connection, which could explain why scripts could acquire the same lock. They would use the same MySQL session and calling `GET_LOCK` twice would succeed in such case.

Any ideas why it is happening or how to prevent it?

Comment: Just to clarify, PHP sessions were not used. To make sure, forcing the session the close at the start of the script did not affect the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got to the bottom of this....

Believe it or not, this bizarre behavior is caused by web browsers, and more shockingly - all of the tested browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox). It turns out that browsers do some sort of special handling for loading pages with the **identical URL**.

**Scenario:** Let us assume were are loading a script `http://localhost/test.php` in two separate tabs, with 2 seconds between each other. Imagine a simple script that outputs the current time, sleeps for 10 seconds and outputs the current time again.

**Expected result:** Each tab makes a request to the server asynchronously, with the second tab being 2 seconds behind the first in terms of execution. Each tab will take exactly 10 seconds to finish execution, with second tab finishing 2 seconds later, relative to the first tab. Tabs will display different output (printed times would be offset by 2 seconds).

**Actual result A (Opera v12)**: Only 1 request is ever made to the server (verified via server access log). First tab takes 10 seconds to finish execution and second tab **immediately** finishes too (not 2 seconds later). Tabs display identical output (printed times are identical).

**Actual result B (Firefox, Chrome, Opera v20)**: Each tab makes a request to the server as expected, but the requests are **synchronous**. First tab takes 10 seconds to finish execution and second tab takes additional 10 seconds, finishing 10 seconds after the first tab. Tabs will display different output (printed times would be offset by 10 seconds).

**Workaround:** Simple artificial change to the URL solves the issue. For example, executing 
`http://localhost/test.php` in one tab and `http://localhost/test.php?` (question mark added) in the other tab.

**Observations:** Setting various caching headers in the script did not affect the results. Default browser configuration was used, no tweaking. Follow up tests relieved that Internet Explorer v10 produced the expected result (surprisingly), making it the only browser to actually work as expected, who would've thought!

In the light of this discovery it is now understandable why the `GET_LOCK` in MySQL/PHP **seemed** to misbehave, which was actually caused by the completely unexpected behavior of the web browser.

Comment: +1 for thorough testing! It's interesting that the browser only makes one http request, like it's re-using the recently cached result to be more efficient. This makes IE actually dumber, which is what we all expect. :-)  You could also test in another way by running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on MySQL when you expect to see two database connections, and you'll only see one connection.

Comment: @BillKarwin part of problem is that I never suspected such unexpected behavior from all major browsers. I just presumed that they made two connections and that the fault was somewhere in PHP or MySQL. Well, lesson is learned - presume nothing when it comes to browsers ;)

Comment: @dezlov -- Thanks for explaining the perplexing problem I found in both FF and IE -- namely that two copies of a test script would not run in parallel.  However, as you noted, an unimportant change to the url allowed the "same" script to run twice in parallel.  Task Manager (on a machine with multiple Cores) demonstrated the parallelism.  (My script was CPU bound, not just a Sleep.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also option that you (for example) are using fast-cgi or other queue method. Depending on the settings - each ip may be restricted to only one running script at once therefore all requests are made in queue one by one making it harder to test. (Had similar problem with production server settings).